# How do I execute get data c# code page_load() using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, azure

Converted `console application c# code` to asp.net application added code into Page_Load() event. which gets data from `Azure Table` and want to display it on page using `simple html`,

**Index.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the table client.
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        // Create the CloudTable object that represents the "DeviceData" table.
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("DeviceData");

        // retrive data
        TableQuery<CustomerEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>();

        foreach (CustomerEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
        {
            // bind data to simple html table 
            //Response.Write("{0}, {1}\t{2}\t{3}", entity.PartitionKey, entity.RowKey,
            //                    entity.Email, entity.PhoneNumber);
        }
    }
```

**CustomerEntity.cs**

```
public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity
{
    public CustomerEntity(string lastName, string firstName)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = lastName;
        this.RowKey = firstName;
    }

    public CustomerEntity() { }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

How can I display data on html page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    Show Data here
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What has jquery to do with this if everything takes place server-side in `Page_Load`? Just bind you data to a DataGrid/DataList/Repeater and you're done. Just drag the control of your choice onto your page and hit F1 if you need a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can create `.aspx` page and instead of `Page_Load` method, you can
>   use a separate `WebMethod` and can call from `jquery` to find the
>   data.

Refer this `URL` which explains this well with a `code` sample and `demo`.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-JSON-data-object-from-WebMethod-PageMethod-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx